# Android Wear: Embedded notification activity not started in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-notifications, wear-os

I have a custom layout notification that is started from the wearable, i.e. only visible on the watch.  The embedded activity successfully runs on a real device, but it isn't started on the emulators.  When pulling up the card to show the custom notification, I just get a black box in the card. The notification is sent from a launcher activity.

It is started in the usual way on the wearable side:

```
    // Build context stream notification
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent( this, NotificationActivity.class );
    PendingIntent pendingNotificationIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
    Notification.Builder builder =
            new Notification.Builder( this )
                    .setSmallIcon( R.drawable.ic_launcher )
                    .setContentTitle( getString( R.string.app_name ) )
                    .extend( new Notification.WearableExtender()
                                     .setDisplayIntent( pendingNotificationIntent )
                    );

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
    notificationManager.notify( 0, builder.build() );
```

Anyone seen something similar?  I'm just curious if it is an emulator only problem or more widespread to real devices as well, since I only have the one device to test on (Samsung Gear Live), which works fine.

Comment: I also have this problem. It's making debugging round watches very tricky (we only have a square watch). Have you found a solution?

Comment: @Sam Not a solution, no - I had to resort to changing my code to skip the notification and directly start the embedded activity every time I wanted to test it on the round emulator. A bit annoying, but at least I could continue testing.

Comment: hmm the problem i have is that the activity seems to get laid out differently when displayed directly vs displayed in a notification